# Can not find AddAuthentification method in Microsoft Extensions Package

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`'s  method `AddAuthentification` on a `ASP .NET Core 2.1` project  though  it seems it does not exist in the package when trying to resolve it.
Instead i have an extension `AddAuthentificationCore` which does not have the same signature.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.authenticationservicecollectionextensions.addauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.1) it should be present for `.NET Core 2.1`.

**P.S** 
I want to use the `AddAuthentification` like :

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options => {
                options.LoginPath = "/login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";

                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) => {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not part of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. It simply uses that namespace so no explicit additional `using` statement is required to have the extensions show up. It will actually live in one of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` NuGet packages.

Comment: I still have no `AddAuthentification` extension.As i said there is `AddAuthentificationCore`